# Bash date formatting error?

Tags: bash, date, format, utc

I get an odd behavior from `date` function where it doesn't convert date correctly.

```
_startDate="07/14/2015 00:00:00 UTC"
echo $_startDate  # 07/14/2015 00:00:00 UTC
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "$_startDate")
echo $DATE        # 20150713
```

As you can see, when I try to convert the format of date, it takes off a day from `_startDate`. I thought it could be a weird round-off error, so I tried with `_startDate="07/14/2015 00:00:01 UTC"`, but `echo $DATE` still echoes `20150713`. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Probably your locale is not UTC but somewhere else, so hour 00 UTC there is in the day before. What do you get if you say `LC_ALL=C date +%Y%m%d -d "07/14/2015 00:00:00 UTC"`?

Comment: @fedorqui That's a one liner, correct? I tried that, and it returns `20150713`. But why should `DATE` variable be concerned with my locale timezone when I specified I wanted `UTC` timezone?

Comment: Add `%Z` to your date output format and see what timezone it thinks you are in. `LC_ALL` isn't the right fix here (right idea wrong env vars). You want `TZ=UTC date ...`. The `UTC` on the input date is the timezone of the input date not the timezone of the output date.

Comment: I think I fixed it with giving in the `-u` flag. What difference is there between `TZ=UTC date ..` vs. the `-u` flag?